# NHibernate Session.Load or Session.Get

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, nhibernate, ado.net, fluent-nhibernate

I have an idea of Session.Load and Session.Get but would like to know its real time implementation. Suppose there are Company and Location tables with n:1 relationship. In the Company edit page, user selects a location and submits the page. By using below code, it gets attached without hitting the db.

```
cust.Location =  session.Load<Location>(selectedlocationid)
```

But meanwhile, if another user deletes the location during this period, exception might occur. This situation may even occur with ADO.NET/Entity framework since we just update the id's without checking existence.

I would like to know generally how to update for this simple scenario. Since web application has disconnected architecture, is it ok to just ignore such possibility and go-ahead with "Load" (or) hit the db using "Get" and check for nulls and proceed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot lock rows before deleting since there may be a lot of delay between viewing a row for delete and actually deleting the row.
Not locking the row is [optimistic concurrency](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa0416cz%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

At the database level implement your [foreign key](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175464%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) relationships so that it would not allow relation to a deleted row. That way, your code would raise an exception if someone deleted the row.

You could catch that exception and alert the user accordingly.

Comment: My bad, I guess I am thinking too much. I completely forgot about the referential integration. Thanks for your reply.